# How to add plugins to CKEditor?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

How to add plugins in CKEditor?

I'm trying to add plugins to the rich editor, I tried something like `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-link` but I didn't know how to add it to the editor, right now it's only showing basics like (bold, italic, link & etc.) but I want to more plugins.

**The Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';


function Editor({ data, setDesc, inputValue} ) {

  return (
    <div className="Write">
      <h2>
        <u>CKEditor with React.js</u>
      </h2>

      <div style={{
        width:"700px", 
        display: "inline-block", 
        textAlign: "left"}}>
        <div style={{
          width:"700px", 
          display: "inline-block", 
          textAlign: "right", 
          marginTop: "5px"}}>

        </div>

        <CKEditor 
          editor={ClassicEditor} 
          data={data} 
          onChange={(e,editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setDesc(data);
            }} />

        {/* <div>
        {addedData ? parse(addData) : ""}
        </div> */}

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Editor;
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ek4o3?file=/src/App.js:4703-4713

Comment: @user1672994 I copied the code and pasted it but I'm getting this error >> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. << I don't why !!